# Start sidekiq from an exploded war

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, jruby, warbler, sidekiq

Our current production deployment uses jenkins to deploy a warble generated war file to Tomcat.  The whole thing works like a charm.  The problem I'm running into however is how to kick start up sidekiq's workers on this machine via "bundle exec sidekiq [options]".  Ideally I'd love to avoid setting up a whole seperate ruby environment on this machine just to do this, but either way to run properly, sidekiq needs access to the exploded/installed apps environment etc.

Is there an accepted way to do something like this?  Is there a better way to startup sidekiq in instances like this beyond bundle?

Comment: Did you manage to run sidekiq from an exploded war ?

Comment: Same question - I am using a war deployment but need to start sidekiq - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/kares/jruby-rack-worker) project may be of help. It allows you to package anything that can be a rake task into a jar file. Their documentation has some specific notes about warbler use. Have a look!

For notes on how to run Sidekiq from outside of the command line run something like this from your project root:

`cat $(bundle show sidekiq)/bin/sidekiq`

You should see some lines:

```
cli = Sidekiq::CLI.instance
cli.parse
cli.run
```

If you read into the CLI class, you'll notice that parse takes either ARGV as the default argument, but you can override it with your own arguments:

```
cli.parse "-q myqueue -e production".split(' ')
```